# Selected attribute for a dropdown is not working with the name property in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

Selected attribute is not working for my angular 4 drop down. But its working properly when I remove the name property.(but then another error is occurring) 
Please help me .

Here is my component.html code

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group FormComponents">
        <select class="form-control" id="employeeType" [(ngModel)]="EmployeeType" name="EmployeeType">
            <option selected>Select Employee</option>
            <option *ngFor="let nation of Countries" value="{{nation.C_ID}}">{{nation.C_NAME}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u please provide your component code

Comment: @SandipJaiswal I have only started desiging the html page (UI design) and found this error still i haven't code the component. Thanks

Comment: You used [(ngModel)]="EmployeeType". then definitely EmployeeType should present in your component. When you will select any option then angular will update EmployeeType variable. Due to two way binding your html will update due to change in EmployeeType which updated by Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Angular behaves differently than your usual HTML.

To select an option in Angular, you have to set the value of your select to the options you want selected. In your case :

```
<select class="form-control" id="employeeType" [(ngModel)]="EmployeeType" name="EmployeeType">
  <option value="">Select Employee</option>
  <option *ngFor="let nation of Countries" value="{{nation.C_ID}}">{{nation.C_NAME}}</option>
</select>
```

In yout components TS :

```
EmployeeType = '';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works.If it is possible  can you please explain me  why my previous code works when I remove the name attribute

Comment: It might be possible, but I have absolutely no idea :D I could have told you if you were to remove `ngModel`, but the name attribute ... Absolutely no idea, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure, are you using a `<form>`? You do not need the `name="employeetype"` if you are not using a `<form>`. The below should work if you are using a `<form>`, if you are not, then drop the `name="employeetype"`.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group FormComponents">
        <select class="form-control" id="employeeType" [(ngModel)]="EmployeeType" name="employeetype">
            <option selected>Select Employee</option>
            <option *ngFor="let nation of Countries" [value]="nation.C_ID">{{nation.C_NAME}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using a form tag so is there any method to work with the selected attribute while keeping the name attribute ?   here is my form tag         
 <form #applicationForm="ngForm">